# Show pane in all windows in tmux

Tags: tmux

I wonder if I can configure a pane in tmux to appear in all windows.

Any hints how to do that?

Comment: There was a related thread on the [mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/tmux-users) a while ago: [“No it can't, panes have to be in one window only.”](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.terminal-emulators.tmux.user/2490/focus=2491).

Answer (score 6):

Of course this is possible, but you would need to run tmux inside a tmux pane.

```
+-------------+-------------+
| tmux pane 1 | tmux pane 2 |
|             |             |
|             |+-----------+|
|             || new tmux  ||
|             ||  session  ||
|             |+-----------+|
+-------------+-------------+
```

How to do it:

1. start new tmux session
2. split pane
3. `unset TMUX` in pane 2 # this allows tmux in tmux
4. start new tmux session in pane
5. repeat 1-3
6. run `tmux attach -t <target-session>` # this is opens the shared session

This does not work as easily if you are running wrappers for tmux, such as come with oh-my-zsh or tmuxinator. And there are probably many reasons you shouldn't do it, I just don't know any of them.

Comment: This is the answer that best matched to my needs. However, it has one drawback: if you kill the server which has the "tmux session attached within tmux", it kills the attached sessions as well :(

Comment: @Werner Killing the server kills all the tmux sessions, attached and detached.

Comment: I wasn't killing the tmux servers, rather the sessions with attach panes as you indicated. The attached panes sessions within the session being kill would kill their own sessions.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a way to do this, but the mirrored panes will be read-only. There's the `pipe-pane` command which sends the pane's output to a command. You can have that command write the output to a file and then from the panes you want to mirror from, you can `tail -f` that file. Example:

```
# In source pane
tmux pipe-pane 'cat > /tmp/asdf'

# In the target pane (or another tmux session or terminal window)
tail -f /tmp/asdf
```

Comment: Dude, this is, by far, the best solution I've seem. By adding `clear` before tails e.g. `clear && tail -f /tmp/asdf`, it improved your answer answer.

Answer (score 2):

no you can't configure a pane to be linked to every window in a traditional sense but you can use tmux's `link-window` functionality to achieve much of this effect. wrap it in a script or tmux session file to link it to many windows at once.

**edit

you will also want to use the `join-pane` feature.